# c++ defining a static member of a template class with type inner class pointer

Tags: class, static, templates, pointers, member

I have a template class like here (in a header) with a inner class and a static member of type pointer to inner class

```
template <class t> class outer {
    class inner {
        int a;
    };

    static inner *m;
};

template <class t> outer <t>::inner *outer <t>::m;
```

when i want to define that static member i says "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token" on the last line (mingw32-g++ 3.4.5)

Comment: Your usage of whitespace makes the last line incredible hard to read correctly. I had to think really hard for a moment to understand its meaning. Basically, you tore apart things that belong together (typename, template arguments, pointer-qualifier) and glued things together which don’t belong together (pointer-qualifier, variable name).

Answer (score 5):

You need to qualify that the `inner` class is a *typename*, since it’s dependent on a template parameter and the C++ compiler assumes that the name `inner` in this context is *not* a type:

```
template <class t> typename outer<t>::inner* outer<t>::m;
```

Rationale: the name `inner` in the above line depends on a type name, `t`. The C++ compiler at this point doesn’t know what `inner` is, because the meaning of the name `inner` can differ depending on `t`. For example, suppose that, somewhere else in the code, there is a specialized version of the `outer` class for `int`:

```
template <>
class outer<int> {
    int inner;
};
```

Now, `outer<int>::inner` no longer names a type; it names a member variable.

Thus, in the general case the meaning of `outer<t>::inner` would be ambiguous and C++ resolves this ambiguity assuming that `inner` does *not* name a type. Unless you say it does, by prefixing it with `typename`: `typename outer<t>::inner`. (In this context, `inner` is called a *dependent name* since it depends on the exact type of `t`.)