# C++ overloading operator with/without defining a template

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, operator-overloading

Problem: overload the default `<<` operator for a `vector<int> v` variable, so that `cout << v` will print each element sequentially. Here I saw one option as proposed by Jason Iverson in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077609/overloading-output-stream-operator-for-vectort)

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, std::vector<T> t) { 
    s << "[";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
        s << t[i] << (i == t.size() - 1 ? "" : ",");
    }
    return s << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

Obviously this should work for any type of elements, however since I am only concerned with `int`, I simplified the function as

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const vector<int> &v){
    for (auto x: v){
        os << " " << x;
    }
    return os;
}
```

It just works fine.

So my question is

1. As far as `vector<int> v` is concerned, what is the caveat of not using `template`?
2. Apart from being general-purpose, what is the advantage of Jason's solution?

Thanks!

---

Deeper thoughts:
The above question was poorly phrased, and thanks to the comments, I believe it makes sense to rephrase it.
Question: in C++, **what is the cost of using `template` where a single-type function is enough?**

---

Credits to [@Marco A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938163/marco-a) and [@Walter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023390/walter), this question could be closed.

Comment: Do you know what a `template` is? If so, why are you asking, if not, go and learn about it.

Comment: What over advantage then general purpose/not having to write the overloads yourself do you need?

Comment: @Walter I know `template` but want to understand its advantage, other than being more general by not specifying the type `T`.

Comment: Overloads != function templates. With a function template you have one piece of code for a huge set of types, with overloads you'll have to define each one of them. Plus SFINAE. Plus template/function differences in the compilation process. It's like comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @NathanOliver Here I am only concerned with the integer type vector, so I think it suffices to overload the operator for just this type should be ok. On the other hand, does defining a template bring extra overhead to the program. One reason that I am asking is I seldomly see codes overloading the default operator outside a class.

Comment: Who is Jason Iverson? What "previous question"? Do you want to link to whatever you're talking about? Is he even relevant to the question?

Comment: @MarcoA. Thanks for insights of SFINAE!

Comment: @Barry So sorry for forgetting providing the link earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main points of C++ is [**generic programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) and `template`s are the way to do this.

The advantage is pretty obvious: you don't have to write the same/similar piece of code more than once and you don't have to debug/maintain similar pieces of code, but just one. (All of this falls in your category "general purpose", so there is no advantage beyond that).

There is actually some disadvantage, because a `template` is not a function (or class). A function (or class) will only be created from the `template` at compile time when it is actually used, whereas your (non-template) function may be pre-compiled. This has two implications: (1) more compiling and (2) that certain syntax errors in the code only turn up when the `template` is used with arguments for which they won't work. The `template` in your post, for example, won't compile if `ostream << T` has not been defined.

Comment: Is there any downside of having such versatility, or does it come at the same cost as defining a narrow-scoped function?