# C++ pointers and for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers

I just started using c ++. I am trying to run a forward Euler, where I use a for loop and pointers. But I don't understand what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void euler(){
  int n = 10;
  double dt = 0.1;
  double *a=new double[n];
  double *v=new double[n];
  double *t = new double[n];


  int vr = 5;


  for (int i=0;i<n; i++){
    a[i+1] = vr + i;
    v[i+1] = v[i] + a[i+1]*dt;
    t[i+1] = t[i] + dt;

  }
  cout << v << endl;



}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  euler();
  return 0;
}
```

The terminal gives me this "0x7fce7cc017d0"

Comment: You're code invokes undefined behavior. The allowable subscript range of `a` , `v`, and `t` is 0..(n-1). Yet your loop indexes 1...n in all three arrays.

Comment: And it uses `v[0]` and `t[0]`, which are uninitiliazed at that moment.

Comment: Here `cout << v << endl;` you are printing the address of array `v`

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector`, as it can expand dynamically.  Arrays are fixed size.

Answer (score 4):

You are printing out the **pointer** itself, instead of the value to which it is pointing.  Try one of these:

```
cout << *v << endl;
```

or

```
for (int i=0;i<n; i++)
    cout << v[i] << endl;
```

Also, as mentioned in a commment, no need for the `+1` in your array indexing.  By the way, this is ***not*** a good use of pointers in C++.  In general, you don't want to use pointers unless you really need to.  With code as simple as yours, you can simply declare arrays.

Comment: ...or `<array>`, or better even, `<vector>`.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you! Do you also know how I can give the velocity, v, an initial value?

Comment: Why is it easier to use arrays instead of pointers?

Comment: @Ivan v[0] = value. 

Arrays and pointers are very similar, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers_vs_arrays.htm and http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~pdiloren/C++_Pointers/neighbor.htm

Comment: @Ivan Re: `Why is it easier to use arrays instead of pointers?` - for once, you won't need to remember deleting what you `new`'ed (you forgot...)

Answer (score 0):

```
double *v=new double[n];

...

cout << v << endl;
```

V is a pointer to an array of n doubles.

When you are printing you are printing the value of the pointer.

Which is why you get results like "0x7fce7cc017d0" because that's the value of the pointer.

If you want to print out the values of the array you must index into it properly.

std::cout << v[0] << "\n"

Answer (score 0):

You can make your original code print the content of vector `v` if you implement `operator <<` for `vecotor`, for example like here:

[Overloading output stream operator for vector<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077609/overloading-output-stream-operator-for-vectort)

Comment: I understand! Thank you for your help :)